# Optimizing the creation of a non-numeric matrix with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

As I was trying to find a way to optimize the creation and printing of a huge 2D matrix, I decided to try out NumPy. But, unfortunately for me, using this library on the contrary makes the situation worse.
My goal is to create a matrix that will be filled with strings with its index. Something like this (where `n` is size of matrix):

`python_matrix = [[f"{y}, {x}" for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]`

And when I used the `array()` function of the NumPy library this way:

`numpy_matrix = numpy.array([[f"{y}, {x}" for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)])`

the time to create the matrix only increased. For example, for `n = 1000`: `python_matrix` is created by 0.032 sec, and `numpy_matrix` by 0.419, that is longer than python by 13 times

Also, `numpy_matrix` prints slower (if you output the full version, not the shortened version), than it `python_matrix` does using `for` cycle

```
n = 1000
def numpy_matrix(n):
    matrix = numpy.array([[f"{y}, {x}" for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)])
    with numpy.printoptions(threshold=numpy.inf):
        print(coordArr)
def python_matrix(n):
    matrix = [[f"{y}, {x}" for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
    def print_matrix():
        for arr in matrix:
            print(arr)
    print_matrix()
# time of numpy_matrix > time of python_matrix
```

1. Is it better to use the standard Python features, or is NumPy actually more efficient and I just didn't use it correctly?
2. Also, if I do use NumPy, the question of how I can speed up the output of the full version of the matrix remains

Comment: Your array creation first makes the list, so its time will obviously be more.  But in any case, making a numpy array from a list does take time. It has to read the list, identify the size, type of elements, convert them to common type (if necessary), etc.  There's a lot of work to be done.  Numpy speed comes when doing math on existing numeric arrays.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I guess the question is: are you sure you want to use NumPy for this? NumPy arrays are really meant for numerical calculations; they aren't a natural choice for handling strings. It's not clear what advantage you'll gain -- unless you choose to instead store an array of the coordinates themselves (as numbers); that might be worth doing. What's your real goal here?

Comment: @kwinkunks Thx! Considering what I have read, I can say that NumPy is not very suitable for my purposes. In my case, I planned to use string (for tests) and class objects. Also, I found it strange because I heard that some libraries can speed up exactly the creation of a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running an `ipython` session and using its `timeit`, I don't get such large differences:

Making the list:

```
In [13]: timeit [[f"{y}, {x}" for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
492 ms ± 3.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Making the array (while also making the list):

```
In [14]: timeit np.array([[f"{y}, {x}" for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)])
779 ms ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Removing the list creation step from the time:

```
In [15]: %%timeit alist = [[f"{y}, {x}" for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
    ...: np.array(alist)
    ...: 
    ...: 
313 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So creating the array from an existing list isn't that much longer.

Specifying the dtype helps a bit as well:

```
In [18]: %%timeit alist = [[f"{y}, {x}" for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
    ...: np.array(alist, dtype='U8')
    ...: 
    ...: 
224 ms ± 2.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Timing prints is more awkward, though we could just time the string formatting, `str(x)`.  I won't show the times, but yes, the array formatting is much slower.  Essentially `numpy` has to go through Python's own string handling code; it has little of its own.

### numeric list/array

For a numeric array, the relative difference is bigger:

```
In [29]: alist = [[(x,y) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]

In [30]: arr = np.array(alist)

In [31]: arr.shape
Out[31]: (1000, 1000, 2)

In [32]: timeit alist = [[(x,y) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)]
171 ms ± 8.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [33]: timeit arr = np.array(alist)
832 ms ± 36.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

However if make the same array with array methods - i.e. not via list of lists, the time is much better:

```
In [40]: timeit np.stack(np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(N)[:,None], np.arange(N)),axis=2)
8.51 ms ± 89.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`numpy` is not an improvement over lists in all ways.  It is best for math on existing arrays.  Creating an array from lists is time consuming.  And it doesn't add a whole lot to string handling.